# SQL LIKE Statment that applies on everything up to a certain character

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-like

My database contains a column for "website" with the following data:

```
foo1.web.com
foo2.gov
doo3.shoo.net
baa.com
baa2.shoo.com
```

I am looking to do a select statement that grabs everything like the variable but only up to the first period, I want to ignore everything after the period:

```
DELCARE @variable varchar(MAX);
SET @variable = 'oo';

SELECT * WHERE website LIKE '%' + @variable + '%' --(but only apply like statement up to the first .)
```

So what I would get back would be:

```
foo1.web.com
foo2.gov
doo3.shoo.net
```

but it would leave out

```
baa2.shoo.com
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT:
Using SQL Server

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Hint: use a substring function to cut `website` to a desired length.

Comment: @1010 SQL Server

Comment: Additional hint: Maybe rather that substring to a desired length, substring to a desired character...like the first instance of `.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can look at only the left N characters of your URL for `oo`. You would get the left N characters by using `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` to find the first `.`

```
SELECT * 
FROM @table
WHERE LEFT(val, CHARINDEX('.', val)) LIKE '%'+@variable+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([website] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('foo1.web.com')
,('foo2.gov')
,('doo3.shoo.net')
,('baa.com')
,('baa2.shoo.com')


DECLARE @variable varchar(MAX);
SET @variable = 'oo';

Select * 
 from @YourTable
 where charindex('.',website+'.') > nullif(charindex(@variable,website),0)
```

**Returns**

```
website
foo1.web.com
foo2.gov
doo3.shoo.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the column you search in named `site`, then I believe you can use something like this:

`` SELECT * 
FROM website
WHERE `site` LIKE '%oo%' AND INSTR(`site`, 'oo')<INSTR(`site`, '.'); ``

Comment: This isnt valid SQL Server syntax. Post just got updated to request SQL Server.